# No activity error found when trying to install an apk from a local file

Tags: android, android-activity, installation

I made an application where I download an APK from an internal server, save it locally and want to prompt the user to install it.
My code is the following:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String path) {
    Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    promptInstall.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(path), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    promptInstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(promptInstall);
}
```

The path has the file of the APK so no problem with the download but when trying to launch the activity I get:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/storage/sdcard/download/internalLocalApplication.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x10000000 }
     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1765)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1602)
     at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:4340)
     at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:4312)
     at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1075)
     at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1054)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE:**
Seems that if I change the code as follows it works! Seems that there is an issue with the Uri?

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String path) {
    Uri fileLoc = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
    Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    promptInstall.setDataAndType(fileLoc, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    promptInstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(promptInstall);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you call `Uri.parse(path)`, the `path` argument needs to contain something like this:

```
file:///storage/sdcard/download/internalLocalApplication.apk
```

Currently your `path` argument doesn't contain the scheme (ie: the `file://` part), which is why it can't be properly parsed.

When Android then looks for an `Activity` that can view this URI, It can't find one that matches, since the URI has no "scheme".

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same error when trying to open an URI generated by the DownloadManager, like `dm.getUriForDownloadedFile(id);`

Fixed it with the following code:

```
    Uri uri;

    Cursor q = dm.query(new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(id));
    if ( q == null ) {
        Toast.makeText(AppContext,
                "FAILED: Unable to read downloaded file" ,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }

    q.moveToFirst();
    String path = "file://" + q.getString(q.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME));
    uri = Uri.parse(path);
    Log.d(TAG,"dm query: " + path );
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, dm.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(id));
```

Comment: Hi. With Android 7 `DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME` is deprecated and the code fails. How can I solve this problem?